# Easy way to copy Accept Language headers to outgoing request?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to copy the header values for `Accept-Language` from an incoming request to an outgoing request I have to make.

Is there any way to write the code better?

```cs
var acceptLanguage = Request.GetTypedHeaders().AcceptLanguage ?? new List<Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.StringWithQualityHeaderValue>();

if (acceptLanguage.Count == 0)
{
    acceptLanguage.Add(new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en-US"));
}

foreach (var item in acceptLanguage)
{
    if (item.Quality.HasValue)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue(item.Value.Value, item.Quality.Value));
    }
    else
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue(item.Value.Value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my result:

```
if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderNames.AcceptLanguage, out var values))
{
    values = new Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues("en-US");
}

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.AcceptLanguage, values.AsEnumerable());
```